# :conditional RegEx to ingore a value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm not sure how title it, But have a RegEx like this:

```
preg_replace('#static\/(.*)(\/|\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})#', 'path=$1$2');
```

It should matches `static/path/to/image.jpg` and `static/path/to/dir/`. Now i want if matched the 2nd pattern (a directory) so replace it with leading slash, but if matched to a filename (1st pattern) replaceit without leading slash.

Example:

```
`static/path/to/image.jpg` should be 'path=path/to/image.jpg'
`static/path/to/image.jpg/` should be 'path=path/to/image.jpg'
`static/path/to/dir/` should be 'path=path/to/dir/'
```

In simple words, I want `$2` to be ignored if equals to file requested with `/` at end. Thought adding `?:` could do the trick but i was wrong.

Is there a way to do such thing ?

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Could you provide before and after examples?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description. Did you mean `'path=path/to/dir' without slash`?

Comment: I said `Now i want if matched the 2nd pattern (a directory) so replace it with leading slash` and example is the same, I mean 'path=path/to/dir/' with slash

Comment: You also said `In simple words, I want $2 to be ignored if equals to /.` That doesn't mean the same thing. Have posted answer to fit the first description.

Comment: @robinCTS You were right, question was a little confusing. Now i edited with better description and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the path is at the end of the URL:

`preg_replace('#static((?:/[^./]*(?=/))*)(/(?:\w+\.\w+)?)/?$#', 'path=$1$2');`

or without the lookahead (faster):

`preg_replace('#static(/(?:[^./]*/)*)(\w+\.\w+)?/?$#', 'path=$1$2');`

**EDIT:** Modified the regex with the added clarification by OP

Comment: I'm rewriting the URL, So something like `static/images.png/` will be replaced to `path=image.png/` with leading slash

Comment: @Omid - Can you add a _complete_ URL example, and the result you want, to your question. That way I can be sure the regex will work.

Comment: Another example added, lemmi know if you want more information

Comment: @Omid - I think I know what you mean. Answer will work unless the path you are after is in the middle of the URL. Wasn't sure how PHP would handle the noncaptured capturing group in the faster regex. Had to test it online before posting it.

Comment: You did it, Thanks, May we be in touch ?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you're just replacing `static/` with `path=` (if a pathname follows), right?

Then just do that:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%static/      # Match static/
    (?=            # only if the following text could be matched here:
     \S+           # one or more non-whitespace characters,
     (?:           # followed by
      /            # a slash
     |             # or
      \.\w{2,4}    # a filename extension
     )             # End of alternation.
     (?!\S)        # Make sure that there is no non-space character here
    )              # End of lookahead.%x', 
    'path=', $subject);
```

Comment: Why you assumed that there should be `one or more non-whitespace characters` ?

Comment: @Omid: Are unencoded spaces allowed in your pathnames? They shouldn't be, therefore `\S` is more specific than `.` which becomes relevant if your string might contain more than just a single path. Your question didn't state this.